# Which version of cocos2d should I choose?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, cocos2d-iphone

I am new to cocos2d.  There are like 2.x and 3.0 versions. If I want develop for iOS 7, should I choose 3.0? What is the difference between?

Comment: you should ask on their forms http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to choose the most iOS 7-compatible version of Cocos2D, choose 3.0. However, the team fixed iOS 7-compatibility in version 2.1.4.

For a basic change log for 3.0, visit this: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/development/

Comment: i find every version of cocos2d very ios-whatever compatible. .02